# Populate select box in rails form on edit page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails form with a select box and various options I want the user to choose from.
_form.html.slim

```
.form-group
        = f.label :year
        = f.select :year, options_for_select(["one", "two", "three", "four"]),
         {class: 'form-control'}
```

The user chooses an option and submits the from which is saved but when  editing an item the chosen option is not automatically selected whereas the other fields in the form are...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you include the rest of the form (or, at least the line where `f` is set)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the options_for_select.  the `select` method will generate that for you.

```
= f.select :year, ["one", "two", "three", "four"], {}, {:class => 'form-control'}
```

The empty {} is for the select options (you can put in :include_blank or :prompt for example).  The second options hash is for html options like class

Comment: It doesn't when you have static options. At least not on Rails 4.2.11.3 and Ruby 2.3.8 where I was having the same trouble. The `selected` option fixed that.

Answer (score 3):

specify the selected value by using

```
   = f.select :year, options_for_select(["one", "two", "three", "four"], selected: f.object.year), {class: 'form-control'}
```